# Cartesian product of array with itself without duplicates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, cartesian-product

How can I do a cartesian product of an array with itself, without including both `[object i, object j]` and `[object j, object i]`?

Currently, I've got

```
array = %w{a b c}
unique_combinations = array.each_with_index.to_a.product(array.each_with_index.to_a).
  find_all{|(first_object, i), (second_object, j)| i < j}.
  map{|(first_object, i), (second_object, j)| [first_object, second_object]}
unique_combinations # => [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

which works, but feels a little verbose.

I could do

```
array = %w{a b c}
combinations = array.product(array)
unique_combinations = combinations.find_all{|first_item, second_item| array.index(first_item) < array.index(second_item)}
```

but that feels like I'm throwing information away, and would only work if the array only had unique items in it.

Another approach is

```
unique_combinations = []
array.each_with_index do |first_item, i|
  array.each_with_index do |second_item, j|
    next unless i < j
    unique_combinations << [first_item, second_item]
  end
end
```

but that feels too imperative rather than functional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called a [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)?

```
a = %w{a b c}

a.combination(2).to_a
=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```